# Scala error handling - if a part of my Scala code fails, I want to execute a function() as part of the program

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, exception

I am new to Scala coding, I have a requirement to execute a function if a part of my scala code fails.
I have tried using Try/Catch but inside catch{} block I am not able to call the func1() function. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

```
object obproc {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  code1

  code2

  code3

  def func1(a:String) {
 //some functionality
 }
 // if code2 fails I have to execute the function as func1("code failed")
}
```

}

Comment: do you mean try-catch?

Comment: you need to figure out how you want to convey failure.how will your code know to call func1

Comment: It doesn't have to try-catch any other way is fine but it has to execute the func1() if the code2 block has any errors/failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply wanted to catch any exceptions in `code1` and call `func1()`, it could be as simple as:

```
import scala.util.Try
Try(code1).getOrElse(func1("code 1 failed"))
```

But this is a crude implementation. What happens if `func1()` fails?

As others have said in the comments, it is worth thinking about how failures are expressed and encapsulated in the code base. And how they can be composed.

If we were using `Try` to encapsulate our failures, we could write something like:

```
def code1: Try[Unit] = ???
def func1(a: String): Try[Unit] =  ???
val composedApplication: Try[Unit] = code1.orElse(func1("failed"))
```

And then at the very top of the application, run it:

```
composedApplication.fold(err => println("failure" + err), _ => println("success"))
```